# Chrome Inspect Element for Native Browser(not Android Chrome) on Android 4.2 Device

Tags: webkit, remote-debugging, android-testing, web-inspector

I have a issue that comes only on the Native "Browser"(not chrome) if the Android 4.2. 
Now, The rendering of my page in Native"browser"App(in some Android systems it is "Internet"), is very different from Chrome App. Also, When i connect to USB and go to chrome://inspect/#devices , It shows my phone(Running 4.2 on Sony Xperia Ray) without any buttons to inspect element.Here is an image which shows the same. [image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vof3O.png]

Now, After some digging i found that inspect element via remote debugging only works on Chrome App and not Native "Browser" App. (not sure about this).

I really need a way to Inspect element on the native browser for Andriod 4.2. Please Help.